# Making a cookie accessible in different tab?

Tags: jsp, servlets, cookies

I have set a cookie in my jsp page say(A). and set its path to "/"(which implies that this cookie is accessible from any where within the domain). I am hosting my server in jboss in localhost. Once the cookie is set if I open a new tab and try to access the cookie from the same page from which I was doing originally, I am not able to access that cookie.
 What may be the possible reason for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cookies are session bound by default (if an expiry date is not set), so should be accessible from any tab.

Comment: I am able to access from different tabs if the server is in another machine. But if the server is local host I am not able to access cookie from different tabs

Comment: Do you access the server as http://localhost or http://127.0.0.1? (The latter will work wit JBoss I think)

Comment: I access it with my system IP address